# R: Adding Labels From Matrix to a Graph

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I generated this random network graph and matrix:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(visNetwork)
library(htmlwidgets)


set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(runif(19*20), nrow = 19, ncol = 20)
mat <- t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) x/sum(x)))
mat <- rbind(mat, c(rep(0, 19), 1))


nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:20)
edges <- data.frame(from = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE), to = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE))

nodes$shape <- 'circle'
edges$weight <- apply(edges, 1, function(x) mat[x["from"], x["to"]])

# create the network graph
network <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
    visEdges(arrows = list(to = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
    visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle")
```

[image]

**Now, I am trying to add the labels (i.e. the decimal numbers) from this matrix to each corresponding edge on this graph (i.e. edges$weight)**

I found these two previous posts ([Integrating the js code in R to make the visNetwork edges curved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162029/integrating-the-js-code-in-r-to-make-the-visnetwork-edges-curved), [Create a visNetwork diagram where edge labels do not overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760628/create-a-visnetwork-diagram-where-edge-labels-do-not-overlap)) - but I am not sure how to adapt the code here to suit my problem.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we could do it, see here https://www.quantargo.com/help/r/latest/packages/visNetwork/2.0.9/visNetwork

```
library(tidyverse)
library(visNetwork)
library(htmlwidgets)


set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(runif(19*20), nrow = 19, ncol = 20)
mat <- t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) x/sum(x)))
mat <- rbind(mat, c(rep(0, 19), 1))


nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:20, 
                    label = paste("Node", 1:20))

edges <- data.frame(from = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                    to = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE),
                    label = paste("Edge", 1:100))                          

nodes$shape <- 'circle'

# create the network graph
network <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visEdges(arrows = list(to = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") 
network
```

[image]

Comment: @  TarJae: Thank you so much for your answer! I am trying to get the labels from "mat" (i.e. decimal numbers) to appear on the corresponding network edges. do you know how to do this? thank you so much!