# R: Understanding Double Lists In The Same Statement

Tags: r, list, matrix

I am working with the R programming language.

In a previous question ([R: Adding Labels From Matrix to a Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76116391/r-adding-labels-from-matrix-to-a-graph)), I learned how to make the following network graph:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(visNetwork)
library(htmlwidgets)


set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(runif(19*20), nrow = 19, ncol = 20)
mat <- t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) x/sum(x)))
mat <- rbind(mat, c(rep(0, 19), 1))


nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:20, 
                    label = paste("Node", 1:20))

edges <- data.frame(from = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                    to = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE),
                    label = paste("Edge", 1:100))                          

nodes$shape <- 'circle'

# create the network graph
network <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visEdges(arrows = list(to = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") 

network
```

[image]

**My Question:** I am trying to understand how this command works `list(to = list(enabled = TRUE))`

For example, suppose I make the following modification:

```
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(runif(19*20), nrow = 19, ncol = 20)
mat <- t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) x/sum(x)))
mat <- rbind(mat, c(rep(0, 19), 1))


nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:20, 
                    label = paste("Node", 1:20))


edges <- data.frame(from = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                    to = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE))

edges$label <- apply(edges, 1, function(x) mat[x["from"], x["to"]])

network <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visEdges(arrows = list(to = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle")
```

[image]

**Suddenly I lose the edge labels on the graph?**

**Can someone please help me understand how the `list(to = list(enabled = TRUE))` statement works and why the modification I made makes me lose the edge labels? Is there a way to prevent this from happening?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on the `visNetwork` package, but it seems to be based on `vis.js` which is documented [here](https://visjs.org/).

In your second example, the loss of the labels is not related to `list(to = list(enabled = TRUE))`, but is due to the fact that the newly calculated labels are numerical rather than characters.

To fix this, you can change this line:

```r
edges$label <- apply(edges, 1, function(x) mat[x["from"], x["to"]])
```

To this:

```r
edges$label <- as.character(apply(edges, 1, function(x) mat[x["from"], x["to"]]))
```

You would need to format the output to improve the appearance, but you get the idea.

In this code chunk:

```r
network <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visEdges(arrows = list(to = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle")
```

The `list(to = list(enabled = TRUE)))` is designed to replicate the javascript options that can be passed in `vis.js` - see the documentation [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/edges.html).

Find the reference for `arrows.to.enabled` and you will see the description:

> Toggle the arrow on or off. This option is optional, if undefined and the scaleFactor property is set, enabled will be set to true.

The JS object is converted to a list in R which is why the syntax is slightly different. Once you see them side-by-side, the structure can be easy to understand.